# Issue while evaluating the condition in javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl

I am fetching one value from controller to jsp and trying to validate the value as follows,

```
<c:set var="healthWorkerOptions" value='${map["healthWorkerOptions"]}' />

<script>
validateSelectedOption(); 

function validateSelectedOption()
{
        alert("test");

        if(healthWorkerOptions != null)
        {
        alert("not null");
        }
        else{
        alert("null");
        }
}
</script>
```

Value is coming from the controller and able see the fetched value with following statement,

```
<p> ${healthWorkerOptions} </p>
```

But while evaluating the condition nothing is happening. What's wrong in my code? I am able to see only `test` alert but not `not null or null` alert.

Any suggestion

Comment: Do you get a JavaScript error in your browser console? You might need to check against `window.healthWorkerOption` if this is being set as a global variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use `el` in `JavaScript` also like below :

```
healthWorkerOptions = "${healthWorkerOptions}";
if(healthWorkerOptions != null)
{
    alert("not null");
} else {
    alert("null");
}
```

Comment: actually I don't want to display the value on UI. For testing I have displayed

Answer (score 2):

`healthWorkerOptions` is not defined in scope of your JS. A debugger should tell you this.

```
function validateSelectedOption() {
    var healthWorkerOptions = '<c:out value="${healthWorkerOptions}" />';

    [...]
}
```